# XMPP API for iOS documentations

Tags: ios, vcf-vcard, xmppframework

Please help me. 
Is there any documentation of XMPP APIs for iOS like the usage of XMPPvCardTemp class methods?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your problem here

Answer (score 0):

There is no XMPP API docs avaialbe at present for iOS.

You can read [XMPP Extension](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/) and implement it in your app.

You can find soruce code for this [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)

Comment: It would be hard to understand the usage of each methods then, well thanks for the answer. =)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this tutorial some method they explained here
[link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/?search_index=1)

Comment: Actually what I really need is the API documentation for XMPPvCard in iOS. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: XMPPvCard comes under XEP-0054 extension. Read this docs http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html and implement same. Already this link "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework" implemented it, you need to create "iq" packet stanza and need to send to server, then handle server response.